# Permutation of lists with overlapping values

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

My brother is a medical student and he came to me with a problem. He and 3 of his classmates have to rotate between two hospitals, say `H1` and `H2`.

- `H1` has a morning shift and a night shift. The morning shift is the most demanding one, so two people have to be there for it. The night shift can be covered by one person, this person would then take the rest of the following day off.
- `H2` only has a morning shift and can be covered by a single person

### The problem:

I'm trying to solve this problem by looking it as a permutation of the following events:

- H1 morning shift (`H1_M`)
- H1 night shift (`H1_N`)
- H2 shift (`H2`)
- Rest day (`R`)

These events would have the following restrictions:

- No 24 hour shifts, so `H1_N` cannot follow `H1_M`
- A rest day always follows the night shift, so `R` always goes after `H1_N`
- 1 student is always on his rest day **except** on the first day, otherwise there is no solution

The problem is how to create 4 schedules, one for each student, which fulfill the two requirements above.

### Attempted solution:

I've created sequences of events which follow the rules set above,

```
import itertools

# Possible sequences from the 4 events
seq1 = ['H1_M', 'H1', 'H1_N', 'R']
seq2 = ['H1_N', 'R', 'H1_M', 'H2']
seq3 = ['H1_N', 'R', 'H2', 'H1_M']
seq4 = ['H2', 'H1_N', 'R', 'H1_M']

# All possible iterations
it = list(itertools.permutations([seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4]))
```

The problem with this is that I don't know how I can generate 4 lists in which 2 of them overlap during the morning shift `H1_M` for every day. If anyone can give me any pointers me and my brother would greatly appreciate it, thanks

Comment: This is more of a math problem than a programming one, but surely you can simply brute force all possible combinations to check if that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I was curious if I could find a solution in python for the problem. I'll ask it in the math stack as well

Comment: I understand the constraints, but what is the goal? A constraint is a rule, such as "If a a person `p` has the night-shift on day `x` then `p` has the day off on day `x+1`" However, what are you trying to optimize? Do you want the hospitals to be always staffed? Do you want to minimize the number of days untill every med student has worked at both hospitals? Minimize the number of night shifts / maximize sleeping? Do you want to maximize fairness (nobody has more night shifts than anyone else) What exactly is the goal?

Comment: Can a med student work two shifts on the same day? That is, can "Sarah" (made-up name) take both the day shift and the night shift on the same day?

Comment: Is a med student allowed to work at one hospital all of the time, or do they really have to rotate? Does it matter how much they rotate/ how often? e.g. Joe works at hospital #1 20% of the time and he works at hospital #2 80% of the time? Does it have to be 50-50?

Comment: In the constraint something like, for every hospital `H` there must exist a day in the next 3 months, such that Joe works at hospital `H`? Or is the constraint that Joe must spend equal amounts of time at each hospital (as equal as humanly possible)?

Comment: It seems reasonable that you might want to allow medical students to work the night shift every day, instead of getting a day off, so long as nobody works consecutive (back-to-back) shifts. For example you could work day-shift, day shift, day shift, day shift every day, but not day shift then the very next night shift, or night shift, then the very next day shift. night-shift every night could be fine as long as you never work a day shift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us name the people ***p1***, ***p2***, ***p3***, and ***p4***.

I am going to number the shifts ***s1***, ***s2***, ***s3***, ***s4***, ***s5***, ...

The shift numbers are chronological.

even-numbered shifts are night shifts.

odd-numbered shifts are day shifts.

```
+----+-------+
| s1 | DAY   |
+----+-------+
| s2 | NIGHT |
+----+-------+
| s3 | DAY   |
+----+-------+
| s4 | NIGHT |
+----+-------+
| s5 | DAY   |
+----+-------+
| s6 | NIGHT |
+----+-------+
```

It sounds like:

- For each night shift, we want 1 med student
- For each day shift there must be 3 med students.
- People cannot work back-to-back shifts. Mathematically speaking, that means that for any whole number `a` and any whole number `b` if it is necessary that person `p(a)` works shift `s(b)` then it is necessary that person `p(a)` not work shift `s(b+1)` (i.e. not possible for person `p(a)` to work shift `s(b+1)`).

In the beginning, we do not care what hospital each person works at. After we figure out who is going to work each shift, we can then decide which hospital to send each person to.

Somebody is going to work the first night shift. It does not matter who. Pick person `p1` arbitrarily.

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| SHIFT | DAY   | PEOPLE |
|       | OR    |        |
|       | NIGHT |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| s1    | DAY   | ???    |
+-------+-------+--------+
| s2    | NIGHT | p1     |
+-------+-------+--------+
| s3    | DAY   |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| s4    | NIGHT |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| s5    | DAY   |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| s6    | NIGHT |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Presumably, you do not want the med students to work back-to-back shifts. So, `p1` necessarily must not work shift `s1`.

We need 3 people for the day shift `s1`. There are only 3 people to choose from for day-shift `s1`

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| SHIFT | DAY   | PEOPLE     |
|       | OR    |            |
|       | NIGHT |            |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s1    | DAY   | p2, p3, p4 |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s2    | NIGHT | p1         |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s3    | DAY   |            |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s4    | NIGHT |            |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s5    | DAY   |            |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s6    | NIGHT |            |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

The rule was that if ***p1*** worked shift ***s2***, then ***p1*** would not work shift ***s3***

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| SHIFT | DAY   | PEOPLE     |
|       | OR    |            |
|       | NIGHT |            |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s1    | DAY   | p2, p3, p4 |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s2    | NIGHT | p1         |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s3    | DAY   | not(p1)    |
+-------+-------+------------+
| s4    | NIGHT |            |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

That is a problem. If ***p1*** cannot work shift `s3`, then we only have one choice:

```
+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| SHIFT | DAY   | QUANTITY | PEOPLE     |
|       | OR    | OF       |            |
|       | NIGHT | PEOPLE   |            |
+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| s1    | DAY   | 3        | p2, p3, p4 |
+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| s2    | NIGHT | 1        | p1         |
+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| s3    | DAY   | 3        | p2, p3, p4 |
+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| s4    | NIGHT | 1        | p1         |
+-------+-------+----------+------------+
```

I think that the med students are supposed to change what hospital they work at. Person ***p1*** is not supposed to do the night shift at hospital #1 every night.

How often do they have to switch off?

Suppose each med student writes down how many shifts they have worked at each hospital. Is it the case that they cannot have their second shift at one hospital untill they have completed at least one shift at all of the other hospitals?

If the med students are not allowed to stay at the same hospital the whole time, then pulling a double-shift is unavoidable.

I worked out a schedule that seems okay.

Anytime you are on two consecutive shifts, you get the next 2 consecutive shifts off to recover.

```
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| SHIFT | DAY   | QUANTITY | p1     | p2     | p3     | p4     |
|       | OR    | OF       |        |        |        |        |
|       | NIGHT | PEOPLE   |        |        |        |        |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| s1    | DAY   | 3        | work   |        |        | snooze |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| s2    | NIGHT | 1        | work   |        |        | snooze |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| s3    | DAY   | 3        | snooze | work   |        |        |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| s4    | NIGHT | 1        | snooze | work   |        |        |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| s5    | DAY   | 3        |        | snooze | work   |        |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| s6    | NIGHT | 1        |        | snooze | work   |        |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| s7    | DAY   | 3        |        |        | snooze | work   |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| S8    | NIGHT | 1        |        |        | snooze | work   |
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The blank spots in the table are actually easy to fill in.

A double-shift cannot be followed or proceeded by `work` or else it would be a triple-shift.

```
+--------------+------------------------------+
| single-shift |      snooze-work-snooze      |
+--------------+------------------------------+
| double-shift | snooze-work-work-snooze      |
+--------------+------------------------------+
| triple-shift | snooze-work-work-work-snooze |
+--------------+------------------------------+
```

Everywhere you see `work-work` in the table, insert a `snooze` before it and a `snooze` after it.

The following is the fully-populated table:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ SHIFT ║ DAY   ║ QUANTITY ║ p1     ║ p2     ║ p3     ║ p4     ║
║       ║ OR    ║ OF       ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
║       ║ NIGHT ║ PEOPLE   ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s1    ║ DAY   ║ 3        ║ work   ║ work   ║ work   ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s2    ║ NIGHT ║ 1        ║ work   ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s3    ║ DAY   ║ 3        ║ snooze ║ work   ║ work   ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s4    ║ NIGHT ║ 1        ║ snooze ║ work   ║ snooze ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s5    ║ DAY   ║ 3        ║ work   ║ snooze ║ work   ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s6    ║ NIGHT ║ 1        ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ work   ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s7    ║ DAY   ║ 3        ║ work   ║ work   ║ snooze ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ S8    ║ NIGHT ║ 1        ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ work   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

You can rotate who has the night-shift:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ SHIFT ║ DAY   ║ NUMBER  ║ p1   ║ p2   ║ p3   ║ p4   ║
║       ║ OR    ║ OF      ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
║       ║ NIGHT ║ PEOPLE  ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
║       ║       ║ WORKING ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s1    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s2    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║ work ║      ║      ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s3    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s4    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║      ║ work ║      ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s5    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s6    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║      ║      ║ work ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s7    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ S8    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║      ║      ║      ║ work ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s9    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ s10   ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║      ║      ║      ║      ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Suppose that nobody has to work a day-shift immediately after working a night-shift. Then, we can fill in the rest of the table:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ SHIFT ║ DAY   ║ NUMBER  ║ p1     ║ p2     ║ p3     ║ p4     ║
║       ║ OR    ║ OF      ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
║       ║ NIGHT ║ PEOPLE  ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
║       ║       ║ WORKING ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s1    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s2    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║ work   ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s3    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ snooze ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s4    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║        ║ work   ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s5    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║        ║ snooze ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s6    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║        ║        ║ work   ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s7    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║        ║        ║ snooze ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ S8    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║        ║        ║        ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s9    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║        ║        ║        ║ snooze ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Unfortunately, if 1 or 4 people snoozes the shift following a night shift, you need 3 people for the day shift, and only 3 are available. There is not much choice who works the day shift on that day.

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ SHIFT ║ DAY   ║ NUMBER  ║ p1     ║ p2     ║ p3     ║ p4     ║
║       ║ OR    ║ OF      ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
║       ║ NIGHT ║ PEOPLE  ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
║       ║       ║ WORKING ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s1    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s2    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║ work   ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s3    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ snooze ║ work   ║ work   ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s4    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║        ║ work   ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s5    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ work   ║ snooze ║ work   ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s6    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║        ║        ║ work   ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s7    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ work   ║ work   ║ snooze ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ S8    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║        ║        ║        ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s9    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ work   ║ work   ║ work   ║ snooze ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

FULLY POPULATED TABLE:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ SHIFT ║ DAY   ║ NUMBER  ║ p1     ║ p2     ║ p3     ║ p4     ║
║       ║ OR    ║ OF      ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
║       ║ NIGHT ║ PEOPLE  ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
║       ║       ║ WORKING ║        ║        ║        ║        ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s1    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ work   ║ work   ║ work   ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s2    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║ work   ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s3    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ snooze ║ work   ║ work   ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s4    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║ snooze ║ work   ║ snooze ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s5    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ work   ║ snooze ║ work   ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s6    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ work   ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s7    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ work   ║ work   ║ snooze ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ S8    ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ work   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s9    ║ DAY   ║ 3       ║ work   ║ work   ║ work   ║ snooze ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ s10   ║ NIGHT ║ 1       ║ work   ║ snooze ║ snooze ║ snooze ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an amazing answer, and your construction is much more direct. Thanks!